.NET 8 Azure database user managed identity
I have an ASP.NET Core 8 Web API that uses Entity Framework Core. I deploy my application on an Azure Linux service app.
My API connects to an Azure SQL Server database. I used the user managed identity on my app service and I added it in BDD.
My problem is that I do not find how to do in .NET 8 to use the connection managed user identity and what should be the format of the string connection.

Does this answer your question? Azure SQL with Managed Identity (user-assigned) failed to login

should the clientId or object id be used to retrieve the credential.

In order to use user-managed identity with Azure SQL Database in .NET 8, you need to enable the Managed Identity for your Azure App Service and then use it in your connection string, you need additionl parameter in connection string which includes Authentication=Active Directory Managed Identity;User Id=ClientIdOfManagedIdentity

Here are the steps followed
I created a user assigned
I added it to the database with db_datareader and dn_data_writer rights.
I then activated it in my AppService
I am still facing the Login failed for user '<token-iden

Could please include your configuration removing the sensitive informaion so that it can be investigated how you are trying.


My problem is that I do not find how to do in .NET 8 to use the
connection managed user identity and what should be the format of the
string connection.

Based on your scenraio and description, as explained in comment, you should have Authentication parameters followed by your Database name and UserId of your ClientIdOfManagedIdentity
So bsically, we have two ways to handle managed identity:

System-assigned managed identity and
User-assigned managed identity

Your connection string should have following format:
string ConnectionString1 = @"Server=YourServer.database.windows.net; Authentication=Active Directory Managed Identity; Encrypt=True; Database=YourDbName";

using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString1)) {
    conn.Open();
}

appsettings.json:
"ConnectionStrings": {
  "DefaultConnection": "Server=YourServer.database.windows.net; Authentication=Active Directory Managed Identity; Encrypt=True; Database=YourdatabaseName"
}

Note: Please refer to this official document for more example and format. If you still encounter the issue, then check this document as well.

My Connection string is  : Server=tcp:SERVER_NAME.database.windows.net;Database=MY_DATABASE;Authentication=Active Directory Managed Identity;User Id=CLIENT_ID_OF_USER_ASSIGNED;

What error you are getting?

login failed for user ' token-identified principal '

I think your azure configuration went wrong, please check this steps and set the correct azure role while accessing the Azure SQL using manage Identity. In addition, Please make sure the Azure Active Directory user is created on the Azure SQL Database.

I don’t understand when you talk to me about User Active Directory. I use a user Assigned that I called test-sql and I put the datareader and datawriter driot on the bdd
